# What is `build` in the context of python?

Tags: python, python-wheel

I'm currently learning about Python distribution packages, and reading through [this article](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), and it says:

> pyproject.toml tells build tools (like pip and build) what is required to build your project. This tutorial uses setuptools, so open pyproject.toml and enter the following content:

It mentions a few times more the concept of *building* Python packages.

As far as I know, at least when talking about pure Python code, Python distributions (sdists and wheels) only contain `.py` source files. So what is meant by the author when speaking about building?

Answer (score 0):

`build` may have two meaning.

In your description `building` means to put all project files into one file with extension `.whl` and/or `.gz` - so later users (using `pip`) will download all as a single `.whl` (or `.gz`).

So we could say that this `building` can mean `packing`.

Second `build` (but not in your description) can be when people install package. Some packages may have C/C++ code (ie. `numpy`) and after downloading it needs to compile it (for your CPU).

So we could say that this `building` can means `compiling`.